# Tessellation with nonagons and equilateral triangles

Tags: mathematics, geometry, tiling

What type of convex nonagon is required to tesselate a plane with equilateral triangles and nonagons? All sides of the nonagons are equal.

NOTE: Partial tessellation of a plane should accompany your answer.

---

One possibility is shown here. In this case, an equilateral triangle is inscribed in a nonagon.

[image: apr17]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one such tiling:

> [image]
>  Start with a hexagon tiling, and truncate every other vertex, i.e. replace it by a triangle. The hexagons become nonagons. Three of its vertex angles remain 120 degrees, all the others are 150 degrees.

Answer (score 4):

As @Jaap suggests by his wording there is actually a continuous family of solutions:

> [image]